# US citizen/HK resident travel documents need to go to mainland China

Tags: us-citizens, china, dual-nationality, hong-kong-citizens

I'm a US citizen and a HK permanent resident. What travel documents would I need to fly to Mainland, China from US besides my Return Home card? Of course, I'll have my US passport for reentering the US.

Comment: Are you a Chinese citizen? Only a Chinese citizen would be able to get a Home Return Permit. Non-Chinese citizens would need a Chinese visa to go to Mainland China.

Comment: I'm a HK resident and I already have my Return Home card. I couldn't get a Chinese visa to with my US passport because of dual citizenship.

Comment: Yes, but Hong Kong permanent residents can be Chinese citizens or foreign citizens (or both). Based on you having a Home Return Permit, we can presume that you are considered a Chinese citizen.

Answer (score 2):

According to Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, you can travel to China exclusively with your Return Home Permit; you do not need any passport or visa.

The relevant bits:

> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid on arrival.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with a Mainland Travel Permit for Hong Kong and
>     Macao Residents (Hui Xiang Zheng, credit-card format).
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Mainland Travel
>   Permit for Hong Kong and Macao Residents (Hui Xiang Zheng,
>   credit-card format) .

When boarding your flight to China, you should declare your nationality to the airline as China (not US) so that they will be able to look up the correct rules in Timatic. If you embark from a US airport, you may need to tell the check-in agent that your card is a "Mainland Travel Permit for Hong Kong and Macao Residents" as they might not be familiar with this document, and it contains very little English text.